# How to get cyber items in candy box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

I was looking through the game's code on the save tab in the status bar and found something called eqItemHatCyber, eqItemArmorCyber, eqItemGlovesCyber, and eqItemBootsCyber. How do I unlock them? I have a feeling that you get the from the developer boss fight but I don't want to mess with that.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. You kill the updated developer.

Comment: @NickS How is this a thank you post? There aren't even any other answers to thank...